# Motorola Moto C Plus, does not recognize USB device on android studio on Mac?

Tags: android, usb, motorola

my Motorola Moto C Plus, and my android system is nougat  7 does not recognize USB device on android studio and I even googled it I downloaded Motorola USB driver even  enable developer options USB debugging is on as well please help besides that I have read many forums I did find  not a solution for my issue .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use The Android File transfer application on Mac for MacBook to show your android device, Check again the USB debugging is on or not .

Comment: only Moto Cplus is not showing or every phone in android studio

Comment: @Kousel, I dont have other android phone but I have tried with other cable as well usb not recognizing but it is only charging

Comment: I have replaced with original cable and it is working thanks